# List recent questions from question poster in sidebar

Tags: feature-request, questions, related-questions

I've noticed that a lot of people, especially ones new to the industry, tend to not only ask questions in a round about way but they will ask multiple related questions right in a row.

Sometimes it's the very same question; but also they tend to just sort of circle around the issue.

I'd like to see the past several questions from the poster on the right side bar.  This will give us an idea of what they are really struggling with.

Comment: Why can't you visit their profile and sort the questions by **newest**?

Comment: Trying to save clicks more than anything else.

Answer (score 6):

This suggestion would be enormously convenient once in a while (because the pattern you discuss certainly exists) and no use at all the rest of the time.

The sidebars are already crowded and space there is at a premium. How much room do you intend to use? Do you expect to put this near the top, or are you going to make me scroll? If I have to scroll, just how much better is that then popping off the the OP's profile as Simon suggests?

Pictures and more details are needed before I'll be willing to get behind this. If I can be convinced at all.

Comment: Actually there appears to be plenty of room on the right.  The tagged through last activity section at the very top right can be made into two columns.  Also having 24 or so related items on the right just looks like noise to me.  Maybe trim that down to 10 related and past 5 of the current OP.